# Laravel Socialite works in Postman but not in SPA

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-400, laravel-socialite

I am in a weird situation where when i test the request to /auth/social/facebook in postman i am successfully redirected to the facebook page, but when making a request to the same route from my spa i get CORS related errors:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=240805606930310&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fsocial%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status
> code: 400.

In my code i have:

Route:

```
Route::get('/auth/social/{provider}', [AuthController::class, 'socialRedirect']);
```

Controller:

```
public function socialRedirect($provider){
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect();
    }
```

and in CORS config:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Comment: `Status code: 400`  means there's a problem with the parameters you provided. This resulted in a response that did not include the CORS headers from Facebook (your CORS settings aren't what's relevant here). The response body itself might give an indication on what went wrong

Comment: there is no response body. it's empty. Any tips in how should i debug what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if you are using InertiaJS or not, but if you are using it for the SPA connector on laravel app, and performing modification on header information for allowing the origin or doing the redirect which may not work, because the request is made up on your inertia request. Instead you can return a Inertia response through which Inertia will able to redirect the request on your desired location.

```
    $redirectUrl = Socialite::driver('driverProvider')->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
    return response('', 409)->header('X-Inertia-Location', $redirectUrl);
```

There is some helpful information on this.
https://inertiajs.com/redirects#external-redirects

Comment: External redirect for inertia worked first time for me - no other changes needed. Thanks again!! :)